# Is there a way to guess which algorithm was used to generate hash key?

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, encoding

The input number is `126594` and the output is `66265784-0a82-4ce0-84e4-4d6f791a6970`

It has 32 chars, so I tried MD5, but the output is different (http://www.sha1-online.com/).

I am trying to generate the post ID on the project done by another developer and he in unreachable. Also changing everything now would take a lot of time, which we do not have.

Comment: Does that input number *always* generate that output?

Comment: This is a UUID, if that helps.

Comment: @biziclop so each device will see different UUID?

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, it looks as UDID. so my conclusion may be wrong on the first place. I thought that he was generating thin number based on the article ID. Seems he was not.

Comment: A UUID, 128 bits, is done with a Java class [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html), one of whose constructors has two longs. Maybe simple shifting and xor-ing. With other examples it might be doable.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do is just try a few different hashing algos. You can use the page you referenced and just try all the different hashing algos they have there.
Actually guessing which hashing function it is based only on the input and hashes is quite hard to do and would probably require much more input-hash-tuples.

Answer (score 0):

It could be MAC+IP address. Generally people use to define it as UUID.

You can try this